# Why am I getting undefined on ctx.fillRect()?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When I'm trying to run ctx.fillRect() from class method im getting undefined when passing class object properties.

``javascript

```
export default classs Reel{
 constructor(gameWidth,gameHeight){
   this.width = 50;
   this.height = 50;

 this.position = {
   x: gameWIdth / 2 - this.width / 2;
   y: gameHeight / 2 - this.height / 2;
 }
}

draw(ctx){
    ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);
 }
```

}

``

It should draw a rectangle on canvas.

Comment: It will be better if you put complete code.

Comment: `gameWidth` is misspelled as `gameWIdth` in `this.position`, although I don't know if that's causing your issues

Comment: @ RSchneyer Nope I made a typo when posting here it still returns undefined.....

Comment: probably because one or multiple of `ctx`, `this`, or `this.position` are defined. Some debugging should tell you which it is.

Comment: My other file contains just defined ctx and import of rell class nothing else....And if replace this.positiong.x and y inside fillRect() everything works fine. Thats why i am confused....

Comment: Have you tried console logging the 4 values you're passing to fillRect? Are they valid numbers? If you console log ctx, do you get the expected context object? And what do you mean you are getting undefined? Because fillRect isn't supposed to return anything

Comment: @Arnaud Rochez Yes i tried to log in all values and they are returning valid numbers. Also when i console log ctx im also getting valid result (context). If i change fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height) to for example fillRect(50,50, this.width, this.height) everything works fine, so the problem is with this.position.x and this.position.y..Very confusing.....